# How does a vector field act on a differential form?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-fields, variational-analysis, jet-bundles

In the definition of the Euler-Lagrange operator (2.6, I. Anderson), the total differential vector fields $D_{i}, D_{ij}$ act on differential forms. How does that work? Feels like Lie derivatives to me, can someone confirm? Thank you!

[image]

Comment: Unless someone happens to know that particular text, you’ll have to provide a lot more context and definitions.

Comment: [Def of Total Vector field](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Mathematical_Aspects_of_Classical_Field/I1UcCAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA56&printsec=frontcover)

Comment: @TedShifrin Here is the text: https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1170&context=mathsci_facpub . More context: https://csclub.uwaterloo.ca/~pbarfuss/TheVariationalBicomplex.pdf , https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oUagwAW3wUQ . These terms are simply defined as some vector fields and some differential forms.

Comment: This seems to be just like the yoga one uses to prove the Poincaré lemma by integrating over the fiber of $M\times I$. Here you're differentiating the coefficients of the differential forms with respect to the fiber coordinates. Yes, you can definitely think of that as a Lie derivative with respect to the vertical vector fields.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you so much for confirming my understanding!